# Which of $I_s$ and $I_p$ will be greater?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

I have two circuits:

1. A circuit with two cells (emf=$12V$, internal resistance, $r'=0.5 \Omega$) and a bulb (resistance=$r$) connected in series:-

[image]

2. A circuit with two cells (emf=$12V$, internal resistance, $r'=0.5 \Omega$) and a bulb (resistance=$r$) connected in parallel.

[image]

Now, if electromotive force is $E$ and the number of cells is $n$,

Current passing through the series circuit,

$$I_s=\frac{nE}{r+nr'}$$

$$\implies I_s=\frac{2\times 12}{r+2\times0.5}$$

$$\implies I_s=\frac{24}{r+1}...(i)$$

Current passing through the parallel circuit,

$$I_p=\frac{E}{r+\frac{r'}{n}}$$

$$\implies I_p=\frac{nE}{nr+r'}$$

$$\implies I_p=\frac{2\times 12}{2\times r+0.5}$$

$$\implies I_p=\frac{24}{2r+0.5}$$

Now, the value of $r$ will determine whether $I_s$ will be greater than $I_p$ or vice versa, will it not? My teacher said otherwise. He said that $I_s$ will always be greater than $I_p$ regardless of the value of $r$. Isn't he wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the [loop rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_voltage_law) to the upper loop, you will get: $$\sum\Delta V = 0 \rightarrow (12V) - (I_p)r - (I_p/2)(0.5\Omega) = 0$$
which reduces to: $$ I_p = \frac{12V}{r + 0.25 \Omega} = \frac{24V}{2r + 0.5 \Omega}$$

Hence, the formula you have obtained is verified to be correct

Hope this helps.

Comment: With the batteries in parallel, only half of the current comes from the upper battery.

Comment: @R.W.Bird, You're right, I've removed that part of my answer.

Comment: Ip does not go through r. Your eqution is still wrong.

Comment: @nasu, Yes I've fixed this mistake. OP's equation is correct.

Comment: @Cross fix 1 to 0.5

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic, Has it not updated?

Answer (score 0):

Safety Note:  You cannot assume that two similar batteries have the same voltage and internal resistance.  If connected in parallel, one may discharge into the other.

Answer (score 0):

The parallel arrangement of cells is equivalent to one cell of emf $12\,\rm V$ and internal resistance $0.5\, \Omega$.

The variation of the current through the bulb, $i$ against bulb resistance, $r$, is shown below.

[image]