# Why doesn't this formula given by my book about cells being connected in parallel work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

**Derivation**:

[image]

Suppose, there is $m$ number of cells that are connected in parallel, each of whose emf is $E$ and internal resistance is $r$. An external resistance R is also connected with the combination. If $E_p$ is the total emf of the combination, and if $r_p$ is the equivalent internal resistance, then according to ohm's law the current $I_p$ will be

$$I_p=\frac{E_p}{R+r_p}$$

But as the cells are in parallel combination, the equivalent emf of the cells will be equal to the emf of any one cell, that is, $E_p=E$. Again, as the cells are in parallel combination, their internal resistances are also in parallel combination.

Thus, $$\frac{1}{r_p}=\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r}+...=\frac{m}{r}$$

$$\therefore I_p=\frac{E}{R+\frac{r}{m}}$$

$$\implies I_p=\frac{mE}{mR+r}$$

Unfortunately, this formula [doesn't work](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/664520/260477) (see my equation for circuit 2 that I derived using the above formula and @cross's equation for the same, which he derived using Kirchhoff's voltage law: his is correct). So, why does this formula not work?

Comment: Cross' forula is wrong.

Comment: Yes, my equation was incorrect. I have tried to explain it here. Corrected the equation in that question now. Apologies for the mistake I made

Comment: @cross thanks for clearing up my doubt!

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic, No problem. Always verify other's work on your own before accepting it. Chances are that you'll find that their work was wrong (like mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that question, I had (incorrectly) followed the OP's diagram. What was missing in it was that the same current $I_p$ does not flow in both the cells. I have corrected this mistake now.

Take your diagram for example. The current $I_p$ occurs because a third of the current comes from each of the batteries. If you apply the loop law to any loop containing one of the batteries you will get: $$\sum \Delta V = 0 \rightarrow -I_p(R) -(I_p/3)(r) + E = 0 $$ which simplifies to: $$I_p = \frac{E}{R + r/3} = \frac{3E}{3R + r}$$
which is the same as given by your equation upon substituting $m = 3$.

Hope this helps.